# Button parameter “command” executes when declared, but not when pressed

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I want to change the color of the button when its pressed.

```
map = []

for y in range(20):
    for x in range(20):
        map.append(0)

def button_map():
    btn_c = ""
    if map[x+20*y] == 1:
        btn_c ="red"
    elif map[x+20*y] == 2:
        btn_c ="blue"
    elif map[x+20*y] == 0:
        btn_c ="orange"
    return btn_c

def button_map_set(x, y):
    if map[x+20*y] == 1:
        map[x+20*y] = 0
    elif map[x+20*y] == 0:
        map[x+20*y] = 1

main = Tk()
frame1 = Frame(main)
frame1.pack()
for y in range(20):
    for x in range(20):
```

---

I have tested this

```
        def test():
            button_map_set(x, y)
```

---

this

```
        test = button_map_set(x, y)
```

---

and this

```
        btn.bind("<btn>", button_map_set(x, y)
```

---

```
        btn = Button(framex, command = test, bg = button_map())
main.mainloop()
```

what happens: it executes when declared, but not when pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bind` and `command=` expect "function name" - it means without () and arguments.

If you need to assign function with arguments then use `lambda`

```
Button(..., command=lambda:button_map_set(x, y))
```

or create function without arguments

```
def test():
    button_map_set(x, y)

Button(..., command=test)
```

if you need run more functions when you press button then use function

```
def test():
    button_map_set(x, y)
    button_map()

Button(..., command=test)
```

-

The same is with `bind` but `bind` sends `event` so function has to receive this information

```
def test(event):
    button_map_set(x, y)
    button_map()

btn.bind("<Button-1>", test)
```

`<Button-1>` means left mouse click.

-

If you need use the same functions with `bind` and `command=` you can use default value `None` for `event`

```
def test(event=None):
    button_map_set(x, y)
    button_map()

Button(..., command=test) # run `test(None)`
btn.bind("<Button-2>", test) # run `test(event)`
```

`<Button-2>` means right mouse click.

---

BTW: own button with 3 colors

```
import tkinter as tk

class MyButton(tk.Button):

    colors = ['red', 'blue', 'orange']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Button.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # current color number
        self.state = 0

        # set color
        self.config(bg=self.colors[self.state])

        # assign own function to click button 
        self.config(command=self.change_color)

    def change_color(self):
        # change current color number
        self.state = (self.state + 1) % len(self.colors)

        # set color
        self.config(bg=self.colors[self.state])



root = tk.Tk()

for __ in range(5):
    MyButton(root, text="Hello World").pack()

root.mainloop()
```

You can add more colors to the list `colors` and it will work too.

Comment: I can see how it would fix the problem, but it made no difference. could it be that my problem lies elsewhere?

Comment: yes, if it doesn't work then you have different problem.

Comment: use `print(x,y)` in this function to see what values you have. If you create buttons in `for` loop then all buttons may have the same value in `x`, `y`.

Comment: btw: if you need only `0/1` then you could use `True/False` instead of `0/1` - and then you can change from `True` to `False` and from `False` to `True` in one line `variable = not variable`

Comment: i use a variable to add a third option

Comment: I can create own Button (using original Button) with extra variables

Comment: an issue found, all buttons are x,y = 19,19

Comment: i know the issue, because all buttons are called btn  all buttons have the same functions/position. is there a way to create multiple buttons the way i want it?

Comment: if you use `lambda` you can use `a=x,b=y` in `Button(..., command=lambda a=x, b=y: button_map_set(a,b))`

Comment: see in answer example - own button with 3 colors